The states of contract haven't change after build_transaction()
transaction = abi_func(**func_args).build_transaction({
            'chainId': 1337,
            'gas': 2000000,
            'gasPrice': w3.eth.gas_price,
            'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(tx_sender),
        })

signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key=private_key)

the values of the variables in contract didn't change, and I don't know why

The limit of gas was too low. Everything works fine after I increase the limit.

Signing a transaction only creates a local copy of a signature in a memory. It does not go anywhere yet.
For any values to change, you need to also broadcast the transaction to some blockchain.
To use build_transaction(), see e.g. tutorial here.

Please read the bit here about the minimal reproducible example and then edit your question to include necessary information
